# Mtouch generation problem with XNATouch and btouch generated admob bindings

Tags: c#, iphone, xna, xamarin.ios, admob

Mtouch generation problem with XNATouch and btouch generated admob bindings.

We are experimenting with a btouch generated c# binding for the AdMob library on the iPhone. We have a test app produced by MonoDevelop/Monotouch. After copying the libAdMobNoThumb.a and the libTouchJSON.a in the project directory, we link it with following extra flags:

```
-v -v -v -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lAdMobNoThumb -lTouchJSON -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libAdMobNoThumb.a -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libTouchJSON.a"
```

This works as expected, the AdMob banner ad functionality is operational.

As a next step, we want tot try this in an XNATouch program. We use the BouncingBox demo available in the XNATouch_1_0 download package. It compiles without errors and runs fine. But if we add the above extra flags (after copying the libs in the demo project directory), the compilation fails with following error messages:

```
Error 1: mtouch failed with the following message:
main.m:9:26: error: mono/jit/jit.h: No such file or directory
main.m:10:36: error: mono/metadata/assembly.h: No such file or directory
main.m:11:39: error: mono/metadata/mono-config.h: No such file or directory
main.m:12:38: error: mono/metadata/mono-debug.h: No such file or directory
main.m:13:26: error: monotouch/gc.h: No such file or directory
main.m:14:33: error: monotouch/monotouch.h: No such file or directory
main.m: In function 'main':
main.m:1811: error: 'MonoAssembly' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:1811: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.m:1811: error: for each function it appears in.)
main.m:1811: error: 'assembly' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:1813: error: 'MTSupport' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:1813: error: 'gcd' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:1838: warning: implicit declaration of function 'monotouch_enable_debug_tracking'
main.m:1899: error: 'MonoDebugOptions' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:1899: error: 'options' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:1921: error: expected expression before ')' token
main.m:1925: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mono_debugger_agent_parse_options'
main.m:1926: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mono_debug_init'
main.m:1926: error: 'MONO_DEBUG_FORMAT_MONO' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:1957: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mono_register_config_for_assembly'
main.m:1963: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mono_register_machine_config'
main.m:1969: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mono_jit_init_version'
main.m:1976: warning: implicit declaration of function 'monotouch_init'
main.m:1990: error: 'gchar' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:1990: error: 'tokens' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:1990: warning: implicit declaration of function 'g_strsplit'
main.m:1991: error: 'aname' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:1992: error: 'basename' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:2001: warning: implicit declaration of function 'g_strdup_printf'
main.m:2003: warning: implicit declaration of function 'g_strfreev'
main.m:2005: warning: implicit declaration of function 'monotouch_register'
main.m:2005: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mono_assembly_open'
main.m:2009: warning: implicit declaration of function 'g_free'
main.m:2019: warning: implicit declaration of function 'monotouch_get_has_classmap'
main.m:2020: warning: implicit declaration of function 'monotouch_map'
main.m:2056: error: 'guint64' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:2075: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mono_jit_exec'
main.m:2075: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mono_domain_get'
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: main.o: No such file or directory
(1) (XnaTouch.Samples.BouncingBox)
```

(These are the original messages where we replaced '/var/folders/hF/hF42FIdhEUmY1y-pGRsu1k+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp159b7497.tmp/main' with 'main')

Can somebody explain how this can be caused by linker options? Take the first error line: it no longer finds header files!? We lack the knowledge to understand this, and would really appreciate some explanations...

Tags: Monotouch xnatouch iphone admob c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a non-issue.

It was caused by the settings of the sample. They still referred to sdk 4.0 which does not exist on my system.

Sorry for the noise.